# How I play my rtsp videos on android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, rtsp, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I mean I have a link like this: `http://15....../a.stream`

I write this code to see the video on android :

```
VideoView  wv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
wv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://15........./a.stream"));
MediaController controller = new MediaController(izle.this);
wv.setMediaController(controller);
wv.start();
```

This code works first.But one day the same code say : 
Cannot play video
Sorry,this video cannot played.

My first question is why that alert me like that?
second question is maybe i play video in another way maybe it is work.Like if I play video in webview maybe it is work? How I play the rtsp video stream on webview?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't play rtsp in webview. Only Flash(rtmp) stream play in browser with flash player.If streams is rtsp, then browser will open it in the external video player.

HTTPS progressive streams are only supported under 3.0+.

Comment: We can change external video player?

Comment: because it is not play to it say same words:(

Comment: If your code is working for some videos then it may be the problem of videos that say sorry the video can't be played.

Comment: but some people with same app says video play.it is not video problem I think but I dont think it is why

Comment: From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) . It says `For video content that is streamed over HTTP or RTSP, there are additional requirements:

      1.     For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom.
      2.     For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM containers, audio and video samples corresponding to the same time offset may be no more than 500 KB apart. To minimize this audio/video drift, consider interleaving audio and video in smaller chunk sizes.`

Answer (score 0):

- WebView plays rtmp as well as rtsp if your device has somehow flash working on it. It won't play without that so API version is important because flash player used to work on earlier APIs.
- The best way to stream live in Android is to use Vitamio. It's the best solution out there. It can play numerous stream formats including rtmp and rtsp.